# CD tray opens and closes occasionally. Sometimes at halfway

Tags: 20.04, cd-drive

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

The CD tray of my Desktop PC opens and closes by itself occasionally.  Sometimes it moves back at halfway. How can I fix this problem?

From its movement I believe it is due to some software problem.

It works really well when I insert CD.  Can I turn it off without any problem by using any method?  Can DISKS app help with this problem?

Since it is not a good solution I don't like to keep a CD inside always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt install setcd
sudo setcd -s /dev/sr0
```

It should output something like this:

```
/dev/sr0:
  Auto close tray:     cleared
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: set
  Lock tray:           set
  Check CD type:       cleared
```

If "Auto open tray" says "set" instead, running `sudo setcd -o0 /dev/sr0` should fix your problem until the next reboot

For permanent fix, create a service file to run the command at boot time

Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` with a descriptive name and a `.service` suffix. For example, let's call it `/etc/systemd/system/dvd-stop-open.service`. The contents of the file should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable DVD auto-open
Documentation=man:setcd(1)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setcd -o0 /dev/sr0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once the service file is created, enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable dvd-stop-open.service
```

Test by starting the service and verifying that the `Active:` field in service status says `active (exited)`:

```
sudo systemctl start dvd-stop-open.service
systemctl status dvd-stop-open.service
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126431/discussion-on-answer-by-edmund-cd-tray-opens-and-closes-occasionally-sometimes).